# How to know what player data belongs to which player in Realms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I have downloaded my Minecraft Realms world and can see the player data, but I don't know which ID belongs to which player. How can I link them?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert from UUID to player name and vice versa with the help of this site: https://mcuuid.net

In case that ever goes down, you can always use the official Mojang API:

- Name to UUID: https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/Etho
- UUID to Name: https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/93b459bece4f4700b457c1aa91b3b687/names

Replace the "Etho" with the player name in the first link and "93b459bece4f4700b457c1aa91b3b687" with the player id in the second link (remove the hyphens beforehand).